# VS Code python autocomplete incorrect for scipy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scipy, autocomplete, intellisense

VS Code's autocomplete does not work properly for deleted names and submodules.

If you import the `scipy` top level package, VS code does not suggest submodule names. In the screenshot below, `stats` is a submodule and it's not in the suggestions. I had a look at `scipy`'s source `__init__.py` file and found out that submodules were put into a `list` and passed to `__dir__`. Also the suggested submodule `scimath` was only used in intermediate processing, which was later deleted, so it is not in the namespace.

The same autocompletion for `scipy` works fine in Pycharm and Ipython. I am wondering if this is a bug.
[image]

Comment: It's not a bug, scipy bundles so many different modules (stats, optimize, etc...) that it's too much memory footprint to load them all from the root import. You need to import from the submodule level where needed.

Comment: But both Pycharm and Ipython works fine in this case? Also VS Code seems to ignore the returned list from `__dir__` in autocompletions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Python extension for VS Code.

One workaround is to use the keyword to give the submodule a different name, like this:

```
import scipy.stats as st
```

The Python extension team is aware of the problem and is working on improving support for submodules with aliases in future releases.